# Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous in a bounded metric space, E.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, uniform-continuity

Let $f$: $(E,d) \to (E',d')$. Assume that $d'(f(x),f(y)) \leq (d(x,y))^2$ $\forall\ x,y \in E$. Assume $E$ is bounded. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

This is what I have come up with so far but I'm not sure it is $100\%$ correct/a good use of the fact the metric space is bounded.

**Proof:**
Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $E$ is bounded, $a = g.l.b(E)$ and $b = l.u.b.(E)$ s. t. $a < x < b$ and $a < y < b$ $\forall x,y \in E$. Thus, since $E$ is bounded $\exists\ d(x,y) = |x - y| < \varepsilon$ 
$\implies d(x,y)^2\ <\ \varepsilon^2$. We choose $\delta\ =\ \varepsilon^2$. Then it follows that  $d'(f(x), f(y)) \leq (d(x,y))^2 < \varepsilon^2 = \delta$. Thus, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

Any tips? How do I make this more concrete/did I bark up the wrong tree?

Comment: Two quick comments:

$E$ need not be ordered so to say anything along the lines of $x<y$ for $x,y \in E$ is nonsense. Also, $E'$ need not have any additive structure so to say $|f(x)-f(y)| = d'(f(x),f(y))$ is mistaken.

Comment: What are $g.l.b(E)$ and $l.u.b(U)$? Don't waste your time saying that they are the greatest lower bound and the least upper bound of $E$. What does it *mean*?

Comment: @DavidBowman I see. Just define the distance as the given $d'$ function rather than assuming its a difference?

Comment: @Inti Yes, the metric on $E'$ is the $d'$ function, as the problem stated.

Comment: @Inti, here are some LaTex tipps: `\to` instead of `\rightarrow` . If you write `$\to$`, the output is $\to$. If you want space, e.g., $\exists \ a\ <\ \varepsilon$, use `$\exists \ a\ <\ \varepsilon$`, so `\ ` for space.  Some people use `\rightarrow` instead of `\implies` because it takes less visual space, but use $\implies$/ `\implies` if sth _implies_ sth.

Answer (score 2):

$E$ is bounded here means that, for every $y\in E$, $M_{y}:=\sup_{x\in E}d(x,y)<\infty$. Now $d'(f(x),f(y))\leq M_{y}d(x,y)$, so $f$ is continuous at $y$.